# Episode of a TV show in which a boy brings pictures to life

Tags: story-identification, tv

I've been looking for a short TV episode (black and white) in which a kid has this gift/power where he could put his hand on a picture from a magazine or advert and he would say “bring” and it would appear in his room or outside. His parents had to lock up all the books and magazines because of this special power.

**Spoiler:** At the end…

> …he gets a hold of this one magazine and brings a heart to life and it appears in his hands and as he's playing with it his parents walk in and have a heart attack and think it ends like that.

It may have been an episode of *The Twilight Zone* or *The Outer Limits* or maybe something else.

Comment: Not an uncommon trope; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49LD4XyME_A

Comment: I recall something similar, but the one I remember I don't think it end with a heart. It could be the same, but I just don't remember that ending. At first I was thinking the child was Clint Howard (But the episode I remembered is from "Night Gallery" where he sees future events) https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0660824/?ref_=ttep_ep1 So I am picturing the wrong face. But I do recall another show where the parents hide the books and magazines. But it may be the things he brings to life only live for a short time.

Comment: Night Gallery had several short stories in each episode. So its a possibility for the source of the story your looking for. But Night Gallery was color, so probably not old enough.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is episode five from the second season of The 1980s *Twilight Zone*, titled "The Toys of Caliban". The story is by Terry Matz, and the teleplay by George R. R. Martin. The episode aired on December fourth, 1986. The following description is [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Toys_of_Caliban):

> Ernest and Mary Ross, are an older couple with a son, Toby, a teen with a mental impairment and the ability to teleport things he has seen by just saying the word "bring". Ernest and Mary have lived as recluses for many years so as not to expose Toby to dangerous images or things that he might summon. When Toby "brings" a living organism, whatever it is arrives dead.
>
> Toby pleads with his parents for doughnuts. After they give their permission, Ernest unlocks a drawer containing pictures of doughnuts, but Toby materializes the doughnuts before Ernest can show him the pictures. Ernest recognizes that Toby's power is growing stronger.
>
> That night, Toby becomes seriously ill. Ernest suspects that since Toby no longer needs to see pictures he may have summoned more doughnuts and made himself sick on them. Though Mary is terrified of the dangers of taking Toby to a public place, Ernest realizes they have no choice but to take their son to a hospital. Ernest and Mary spend the night at the hospital and take Toby home the next day. Their guarded, reclusive behavior attracts the attention of a social worker, Miss Kemp, particularly after they refuse to let Toby see a magazine she offers to him.
>
> At home Toby summons the magazine and eagerly looks through it. Seeing a diagram of a heart, he "brings" the nearest one, which happens to belong to Mary. She instantly collapses, dead. Following Mary's funeral, Kemp interviews the Ross family neighbors, learning how they never let Toby venture outside or play with others. She begins to build a case to remove Toby, unless Ernest enrolls his son in a school for the mentally impaired. Cornered, Ernest explains the situation to Kemp, having Toby demonstrate his power by summoning real items from images in a picture book. Despite witnessing the truth, Kemp believes Toby needs professional help. Ernest insists that if psychologists and scientists discover just what his son can do, Toby will be both feared and exploited for his unique power. Kemp refuses to remain quiet, but suddenly leaves in horror when Toby, overwhelmed by their argument and seeing Mary's photograph, wants his mother and summons her corpse to an armchair.
>
> While burying Mary's body in the backyard, Ernest hears a distant police siren. He tells her that it is finally time. Ernest then sits with his son, tells him he loves him, and presents him with a picture of a sunset. Toby "brings" what he sees, incinerating them both instantly, destroying the Ross home as the police and Kemp arrive.

Comment: Episode on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEu2W9sMsew

Comment: They certainly got lucky, hmmm? Imagine if he had actually been powerful enough to move the whole Sun.

Comment: Omg!!! Yes this is it!!! Thank you! I saw this episode when I was about 8 yrs old. Now 40 and periodically would Google some search words looking for this episode because it just stuck with me as a comic fan and when asked what would my super power be this one would come to mind. I finally got my answer and rewatched the episode on YouTube after 32 yrs. Omg it hit hard since I have 2 young autistic sons now. Thank you!!!